# TextView.getMinHeight() in < 16 API

Tags: android

[TextView.getMinHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMaxHeight%28%29) appears in API 16. But [TextView.setMinHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMinHeight%28int%29) appears in API 1. Where is any possible way to get min height in pre API 16 version without reflection?

Comment: just a thought (without checking a code) - extend TextView and write your own getMinHeight? and override setMinHeight so you can store that in your subclass before calling super.

Comment: @max good point. This will work in most cases. But what if I am using a lib? Your method makes to much pain. Maybe there is some other way.

Comment: well, I'd love to know the other way :) I had a similar problem with TextView.getLineSpacingExtra() method, introduced in API 16, while the backing field was there since API 1, I ended up using Reflection in versions below 16.

Comment: Just tried using reflection with no success (it seems there's no private field named mMinHeight in pre api 16). Best way I've found is to define the minimumHeight as a dimen value and than read it using getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.my_dimen );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(view)` from support-v4 library.

Comment: This method is actually using reflection to get minHeight from <16. I suppose it is the right answer at present day

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get it without reflection.

The field is called mMaximum. It can hold a value in pixels or in lines of text, that's why it's not called mMaxHeight.

Saving the value in setMaxHeight() is not ideal, because there's also setMaxLines() method, which changes the max mode and effectively clears the max height value. You would have to overload all methods writing mMaximum field.

Answer (score -2):

short answer:

```
View.getLayoutParams().height 
View.getLayoutParams().width
```

other possibilities :

> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see Layout for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight().
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling getWidth() and getHeight().

ways:

- using the famous OnGlobalLayoutListener

  This is one of the most used mechanisms to get the view dimensions. You attach a Global Layout Listener to the view hierarchy. It helps you actually get the   width of all the views in your view heirarchy:
- by forcing a measurement of the View

  ```
  View.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  int widht = View.getMeasuredWidth();
  int height = View.getMeasuredHeight();
  ```

Comment: The question is about minimumHeight not measuredHeight